# opening external wepage and closing it when redirected to particular url in ionic framework

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, hybrid-mobile-app, ionic-framework

I am trying to create a simple mobile app where in the user will login with oauth login on our django server. User will first try to perform an action if the user is not authenticated the server will send an error and depending up on the error user will be shown a modal with facebook, twitter and google button this button directs the user to the server and from there to facebooks, twitters or googles login page and the user logs in. I implemented the complete flow but after completing the login I am unable to close the page which I opened.Here is the code snippet.

```
$scope.twitterLogin = function() {
    var loginUrl = $scope.twitterLink;
    var socialLoginWindow = window.open(loginUrl, '_blank', 'location=no,toolbar=yes');
    socialLoginWindow.addEventListener('loadstart', function (event) {
        var url = event.url,
        params = {},
        // get uri
        parts = url.split('?'),
        uri,
        urlParams,
        loading;
        console.log(url);
        alert(url);

        // if there is an uri
        if (parts[1]) {
            uri = parts[1];
            // get uri params
            urlParams = uri.split('&');

            // get uri params and store them with key, value
            angular.forEach(urlParams, function (paramString) {
                var param = paramString.split('=');
                params[param[0]] = param[1];
            });
        }

        // if there is an email param or an error -> close the window
        if (params.email || params.error) {
            socialLoginWindow.close();
        }
    });
};
```

(the event listener is also not working) After the problem occurred I started with new project where in there was just a button and on ng-click on that button . I called the function below.

```
$scope.outofwrld = function() {
    try {
        alert("1");
        var loginUrl = "http://www.google.com/"
        window.open(loginUrl, '_self', 'location=no,toolbar=yes');
        alert("2")
    } catch (err) {
        alert(err);
    }
}
```

but now the alerts are working well but I cant see the window. I suppose that the window is being opened in the background if so how do I bring it to the foreground and close it. 
P.S. I am using cordova inappbrowser plugin

Comment: Are you still facing issue on this one @Sar009?

Comment: @V31 no its fixed now. What happened was I installed inappbrowser plugin after adding android platform. But when I added inappbrowser then added android platform the problem was solved. I even tried to delete the android platform then again added android platform but it didnt help. Anyway the problem is solved now but i dont know what exactly caused the problem.

Comment: Inappbrowser is the solution as window.open will create a new window which will have no relation to the app window...inappbrowser will open a child window and have listeners to handle start stop events

Comment: I have the same problem but with the ionic browser platform.  Tried starting over and adding the cordova plugin first but still fails with 404.  eventListener() isn't catching callback.